# CSS 'after' for inner element whose parent is not the last child

Tags: css

I have a structure as follows:

```html
<div class="outerClass">
  <a href="#">
    <li class="someClass">Some Content</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li class="someClass">Some Content</li>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to apply an after for the li. The consideration here is that the after should only be applied if it's parent 'a' is not a last child of div.outerClass.

I've tried the following code:

```css
.outerClass > a:not(last-child) > li.someClass:after {
  content: '|';
}
```

However this is not working. Any insights here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the colon before `last-child`:

```
.outerClass > a:not(:last-child) > li.someClass:after {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```css
.outerClass a:not(:last-of-type) > li:after {
    content: "|";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerClass">
    <a href="#">
        <li class="someClass">Content</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li class="someClass">Content</li>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, something like this should work

```css
.outerClass > a + a  > li.someClass:before {
  content: '|';
}
```

```html
<div class="outerClass">
<a href="#">
<li class="someClass">Content</li>
</a>
<a href="#">
<li class="someClass">Content</li>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below snippet.

I have given `color: red;` to distinguish.

```css
.outerClass a:not(:last-child) li.someClass::after {
  content: "|";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerClass">
  <a href="#">
    <li class="someClass">Content</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li class="someClass">Content</li>
  </a>
</div>
```